# How do I make my 'Location' != null as a conditional statement in a button?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to add an onClicklistener to a Button; so when I press it, it animatesTo user location. However, if there is no user location and the button is pressed, it crashes due to user location = null. How do I make it run ONLY when it is not equal to null?

I have tried  -

```
private void myLocationButton() {
    MapView mp = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    final MapController mapController = mp.getController();
    final Button myLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myLocationButton);
    myLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myLocationButton.isClickable()) {
                mapController.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
                mapController.setZoom(17);

            }

        }
    });

}
```

This is a long post, thank you for your ample time.

Comment: `myLocationGeoPoint` is always `null`? You only update it once at the start so it is probably null there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myLocationButton.isClickable() && myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() != null) {
                mapController.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
                mapController.setZoom(17);

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it nearly right. But you have to get a fresh `Location` object since it has to be `!= null` in the moment you hit the button. I also doubt that you need the `isClickable()` check since you just got clicked.

```
myLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Location userLocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        if (myLocationButton.isClickable() && userLocation != null) {
            mapController.animateTo(userLocation);
            mapController.setZoom(17);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using the `userLocation` variable here because

```
if (myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() != null) {
    mapController.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
}
```

can still throw a `NullPointerException` since you get a new result on the second call to `getMyLocation` and that might be `null` again. I should be safe though since `getMyLocation` probably never changes back to `null` once it has a real location.